# Replacing gas range - OLD gas valve won’t turn off

Tags: gas

[image: freaking old gas valve][image: hole at the back of the valve]

We’re replacing our gas range. The gas guy told us it was super easy to just shut off the valve and unhook the old one, hook up the new one. But this valve is apparently freaking old! It won’t budge. It almost seems like it’s locked in place, but it doesn’t have a tightening nut like other valves. There’s a hole in the opposite side of the valve, which I took a picture of above. I can’t find anything on YouTube or google that looks like this thing! Please help! So frustrated.

Comment: May I suggest that you spend a hundred bucks and have a gas fitter replace the valve for you. And the flex line is looking a little less than good. You don't want to be messing around with old gas lines unless you are totally confident in your abilities.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. My thoughts? Be safe: hire a plumber (@JoeFala: posted at same time, and completely agree.)

Comment: I agree with Joe Fala and Daniel Griscom on this one. Don't mess with gas unless you are **really** comfortable with it. When I replaced my cooktop I got my plumber in to do it (and it was much newer/better shape than your current situation) - where I would have tackled the job myself it were "only" electric or water, gas is just too risky. A tiny leak due the valve not quite closed or (worse) cracked, and you now have a much bigger problem.

Comment: Looking at the photo, you don't want to use that goose-neck again and if the valve is giving you that much trouble, I'd just have that replaced too. Gas lines have to be completely air-tight so there's little room for sloppiness or error.